# Input documents to LDA

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

Assume I have N text documents and I run LDA in the following 2 ways,

- run LDA over the N documents at once
- run on each document separately, so for N documents you run the algorithm N times

I'm aware of what number of topics to choose as well; in the first case i can select N to be the number of topics (assuming each document is about a single topic) but if I run it on each document separately not sure how to select the number of topics as well...?

What's going on in these two cases?

Comment: Is there any need to run LDA on the document separately?

Comment: I'm not sure why I want to do that but just curious if this is a stupid thing to do or like that

Comment: @KillBill I'm afraid it really doesn't make any sense to run LDA on single documents.

Comment: @drevicko can I ask why it really doesn't make any sense then?

Comment: @KillBill topic models try to balance slicing up documents (assigning bits to topics) and keeping topics coherent, given the priors (Dirichlet in the case of LDA - they try to make topics sparse). With only one document, there's no other topic assignements to compare to. With small \beta (word sparsity in topics) and medium \alpha (documents able to mix a few topics) I guess you'd get frequent words forming their own one-word topics and infrequent words randomly grouped. In any case, you wouldn't get topics in the sense of semantic themes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but I still don't get how beta and alpha affects the topic quality. If you have any good reference for me i would like to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latent Dirichlet Allocation is intended to model the topic and word distributions for each document in a corpus of documents.

Running LDA over all of the documents in the corpus at once is the normal approach; running it on a per-document basis is not something I've heard of. I wouldn't recommend doing this. It's difficult to say what would happen, but I wouldn't expect the results to be near as useful because you couldn't meaningfully compare one document/topic or topic/word distribution with another.

I'm thinking that your choice of `N` for the number of topics might be too high (what if you had thousands of documents in your corpus?), but it really depends on the nature of the corpus you are modelling. Remember that LDA assumes a document will be a distribution over topics, so it might be worth rethinking the assumption that each document is about one topic.

Comment: @KillBill Not a problem. If you found it helpful, remember to come back and upvote and accept.

Comment: Hi sorry I have a question to ask. Lets say I have 5 documents which I THINK of regarding 5 different topics. So if I'm applying LDA is it wrong to set no of topics = 5?

Comment: @KillBill Not at all. I think the last paragraph of my answer covers this, but I guess what I'm getting at is that the choice for `N` is not an easy one. Perhaps the best approach is to simply try running the algorithm with a range of different settings and compare the results to your intuition of what the document/topic distributions should look like.

Answer (score 0):

LDA is a statistical model that predicts or assigns topics to documents, it works by distributing the words of each document over topics, (randomly the first time) then repeats this step a number of iterations (could be 500 iterations) until the words that are assigned to the topics are almost stable, now it can assign N topics to a document according to the most frequent words in the document that has a high probability in the topic.

so it does not make sense to run it over one document since the words that is assigned to the topic in the first iteration will not change over iterations because you are using only one document, and the topics that is assigned  to document will be meaningless